# Verify google reCaptcha fails

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, captcha

I have a problem with google reCaptcha,

I want captcha to work like this http://www.superlike.net/login.php?user=VALUE

Where user=value will be hidden in login form of google captcha
Example - `<input name="user" type="hidden" value="VALUE">`

When I try to use like this google is unable to verify captcha and captcha skips to login page without verifying captcha.
I used -

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="login.php" method="get">
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LduUwYTAAAAADIPfxdfl5C-61c45uABYBT3MIlb"></div>
<input name="user" type="hidden" value="<?php echo("".$_GET['user']."");?>">
<input type="submit"  value="Log In" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am currently using - http://www.9lessons.info/2014/12/google-new-recaptcha-using-php-are-you.html

But when I use this it automatically skips captcha and user logs in.

Any way to do it easily and verify captcha on single page with javascript or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello i solved this question

```html
<?php
include("db.php");
session_start();

$msg='';
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
$recaptcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
if(!empty($recaptcha))
{
include("getCurlData.php");
$google_url="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
$secret='SECRETKEY';
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$url=$google_url."?secret=".$secret."&response=".$recaptcha."&remoteip=".$ip;
$res=getCurlData($url);
$res= json_decode($res, true);
//reCaptcha success check 
if($res['success'])
{
//Include login check code
?>
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://easyliker.com/login.php?user=<?php echo("".$_GET['user']."");?>">
<?php
}
else
{
$msg='Please try again!';
}

}
else
{
$msg='Please try again!';
}

}
?>
```

This worked for me!

Comment: You should indent your code for more readability http://mrbool.com/importance-of-code-indentation/29079